# Correct way of including remote CSS style sheet in OpenSocial gadget module XML

Tags: css, opensocial

What is the correct/recommended way of including remote CSS style sheet in OpenSocial gadget module XML?

I hope we CAN use remote CSS (to enable client caching etc), so that we can get rid of inline styling...

Should a link tag be included in the CDATA section of the html typed Content tag below, or what are your suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
    <ModulePrefs title="My App title">
        <Require feature="opensocial-0.8" />
    </ModulePrefs>
    <Content type="url" view="mobile" href="somemobileplace" />
    <Content type="html">
    <![CDATA[
<div>some html content</div>
    ]]>
        </Content>
    </Module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a reply that it's ok to include things like remote js script files, style sheets in the body section.

I also read in an Open Social book that these things actually get moved into the header section once displayed by the container.